# How to cut angled holes in PVC pipe?

Tags: pipe, pvc, cutting

I need to join different sized pipes together at a 45 degree angle, but am struggling when it comes to what methods are available.

The main pipe is 75mm radius, the smaller is ~40mm. I've opted to 3D print the smaller pipe, so I don't need to worry about messing with that at all.

[image: Exploded view (side profile)]
[image: Required hole (front profile)]

As you can see it's an awkward shape due to the curvature of the main pipe, plus I'm worried about warping the cut by putting excess weight on it. The only method I've come up with so far is using a pair of hand nibblers, but I'm not sure how well they'd work on a curved surface.

Any ideas / suggestions? (I need to do a few of these joins, and the cost of pvc saddles a bit silly).

Comment: If it's plumbing, spend the money for fittings, this won't pass code/inspection.

Comment: For any liquids, sewerage etc., you're better off using the proper fittings. Leakproofing can be a nightmare.

Comment: It's a small aeroponic system, I'll save the real plumbing for professionals!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate way would be to:

- Make a jig out of wood that will hold the pipe to be drilled

  - The jig could be flat or have the desired 45° angle built into it.
  - Building it flat allows it to be used for drilling holes into pipe at any desired angle in the future, making it more useful
- Clamp the jig to the table of a drill press.

  - Either have the drill press table level (for a jig with the angle built in) or tilt it to 45° (for a "flat" jig).
- Drill the hole with an appropriately sized bit.

  - I would use a hole saw from a set with a replaceable pilot bit.
  - Replace the supplied bit with a long one that will reach the pipe before the edge of the cutter will reach it.
  - Use the long pilot bit to ensure that the center of the hole is where you want it to be.

A hole-saw set like this:

[image: hole saw set in plastic case]
<sup>image courtesy of lowes.com. No endorsement intended or implied</sup>

Has a pilot bit that can be replaced. Simply purchase a longer bit that will fit so that the pilot bit hits the pipe before the larger cutter hits, like this crude drawing:

[image: crude drawing of hole saw hitting pipe]
<sup>image courtesy of lowes.com. No endorsement intended or implied. Edited by me.</sup>

Where the red line indicates the pipe and the blue line indicates the longer drill bit.

This is the kind of drill press (or "pillar/post drill" as it's called in some countries) I'm referring to. This model has a 10" (254mm) capacity between the the chuck and the lowest position of the table:

[image: Drill press on floor]
<sup>Image courtesy of HarborFreight.com customer review. Note that this shows it sitting on the floor, not yet installed on a bench top. Click  to embiggen.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the visualization, now I know what I should be aiming for.

(Not asking for Specific products) Do you have a recommendation for the drill press? I can see plenty of "manual" ones that I could stick my handheld drill in, but none of them look large enough for the 150mm diameter pipe. Am I missing something obvious or am I looking at the wrong thing?

Comment: I have a bench-top drill press in my garage/shop - it is a stationary tool (I believe the British _and others around the world_ call it a "post drill" or "pillar drill"). There are jigs that are designed to hold a hand-held drill to allow you to drill more precisely, though I would agree with you that finding one with a large enough capacity to hold your pipe may be difficult. (con't...)

Comment: ... If this is something that you're going to be doing a lot of, an investment in the proper tooling may be worthwhile. If not, talk with friends/neighbors to see if someone has one, or look for a local Maker Space/shared workshop to see if you can rent time/space for an afternoon for your one-time project.

Comment: @Caia something that just occurred to me: You might want to pre-drill a small dimple into the pipe at a 90° angle, or possibly use a file to make a little scratch in the pipe before drilling. This will give the pilot bit something to bite into instead of allowing it to slide slightly "downhill" (to the right in my mock-up, above) as it attempts to bite into the plastic. It depends on how precise you need the location of the hole to be.

Comment: This will work, but needs a steady, strong hand as one side of the holesaw will start before the other, causing it to jump - a lot. Very, very slowly is the way to go.

Comment: That's why I suggested the drill press/pillar drill and a long pilot bit, @Tim. The press will hold the bit steady and the pilot bit _should_ help keep it steadied, as well. Your point is valid, though, when the outside of the hole saw starts to hit the pipe, slow going is warranted, though I thought that was reasonably obvious. Maybe it was not as obvious to everyone...

Comment: My jaws, and yours, may open enough for a 3" pipe - although the depth probably would not accommodate it. And unless it was a pedestal drill with Morse taper, costing lots, it wouldn't do the job - the diy ones are really toys.

Comment: We may be talking about different tools, @Tim. See updated post.

Comment: Pillar - post - pedestral drill. All the same. As I say, the ones for the home market are really too small for all except drilling small holes in bits of wood. The serious ones - with Morse fittings, wouldn't be worth buying just for that job. Having said that, I bought mine, maybe 50 yrs old, for less than a new Micky Mouse one!

Answer (score 0):

A jig to hold a holesaw and the pipe to be drilled is one method.

Start with a block of wood (or whatever material, it doesn't matter much if it's solid-enough.)

You drill a hole for the pipe, you drill the hole for the hole-saw to run in at the correct angle to the hole for the pipe, you fasten the pipe in place so it cannot slide or rotate, and run the hole-saw into the hole-saw hole to cut the hole in the pipe.

The smaller pipe can be easily done (**a lot faster** than 3D printing one) by making a similar jig, but with a sanding drum the same size as the larger pipe, that you feed the smaller pipe against until it's fully "fish-mouthed" to shape. That can also be done freehand with some practice, or with a less robust jig/guide, if you use care.

Comment: I spent more time finding pictures. :)